# Is this correct vector implementation of gradient descent for multiple theta values?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, neural-network, gradient-descent

This is my matlab code to predict [1;1;1] given [1;0;1] :

```
m = 1; 
alpha = .00001; 

x = [1;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0]; 
y = [1;1;1;0;0;0;0;0;0]; 
theta1 = [4.7300;3.2800;1.4600;0;0;0;4.7300;3.2800;1.4600]; 
theta1 = theta1 - (alpha/m .* (x .* theta1-y)' * x)' 
theta1 = reshape(theta1(1:9) , 3 , 3) 
sigmoid(theta1 * [1; 0; 1]) 


x = [1;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0]; 
y = [1; 1; 1;0;0;0;0;0;0]; 
theta2 = [8.892;6.167;2.745;8.892;6.167;2.745;8.892;6.167;2.745]; 
theta2 = theta2 - (alpha/m .* (x .* theta2-y)' * x)' 
theta2 = reshape(theta2(1:9) , 3 , 3) 
sigmoid(theta2 * [1; 0; 1]) 


x = [1;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0]; 
y = [1; 1; 1;0;0;0;0;0;0]; 
theta3 = [9.446;6.55;2.916;9.351;6.485;2.886;8.836;6.127;2.727]; 
theta3 = theta3 - (alpha/m .* (x .* theta3-y)' * x)' 
theta3 = reshape(theta3(1:9) , 3 , 3) 
sigmoid(theta3 * [1; 0; 1])
```

I'm computing theta1, theta2, theta3 individually but I think they 
should be linked between each computation ?

Though gradient descent appears to be working as :

```
sigmoid(theta1 * [1; 0; 1]) =
    0.9999
    0.9986
    0.9488

sigmoid(theta2 * [1; 0; 1]) =  
    1.0000
    1.0000
    0.9959

sigmoid(theta3 * [1; 0; 1]) = 
    1.0000
    1.0000
    0.9965
```

This shows for each theta value (layer in the network) the prediction is moving closer to [1;1;1]

Update : sigmoid function :

```
function g = sigmoid(z)
g = 1.0 ./ (1.0 + exp(-z));
end
```

Update2 :

After extended discussion with user davidhigh who provided key insights have made following changes :

```
x = [1;0;1]; 
y = [1;1;1]; 

theta1 =

    4.7300    3.2800    1.4600
         0         0         0
    4.7300    3.2800    1.4600

theta2 =

    8.8920    8.8920    8.8920
    6.1670    6.1670    6.1670
    2.7450    2.7450    2.7450

theta3 =

    9.4460    6.5500    2.9160
    9.3510    6.4850    2.8860
    8.8360    6.1270    2.7270
```

The crux of my issue is that I don't feed output of each layer into the next layer, once I made this change I get better result :

```
z1 = sigmoid(theta1 * x)

z1 =

    0.9980
    0.5000
    0.9980

z2 = sigmoid(theta2 * z1)

z2 =

    1.0000
    1.0000
    0.9989

z3 = sigmoid(theta3 * z2)

z3 =

    1.0000
    1.0000
    1.0000
```

z3 is the predicted value which correctly is `[1;1;1;]` whereas previously it is approx `[1;1;1;]`

Comment: One problem is you didn't specify the model which you want to learn. You've got a sigmoid in your code, but that does not seem to appear in your gradient. Moreover, in your gradient all theta's should appear, not only the one you're optimizing right now. So state the model, then I can give you an answer.

Comment: @davidhigh is model I want to learn not stated as ? : y = [1;1;1;0;0;0;0;0;0];

Comment: @davidnigh ive added sigmoid function

Comment: I didn't mean the sigmoid. You need a mathematical function `y = f(x; theta1, theta2, theta3)` in which you input your `x` vector (as well as the theta parameters) and which returns the predicted target `y`. Only then you can optimize the parameters by applying gradient descent.

Comment: @davidhigh my understanding is that the predicted value is the result of sigmoid(theta3 * [1; 0; 1]) as theta3 represents the parameters for controlling the output to the final layer. theta1, theta2. theta3 have been computed as part of forward & back propagation

Comment: see my answer which tries to clarify certain things. Particularly, the result of you `sigmoid(...)` calls should be *one-dimensional* numbers (at least if you use the usual model).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111915/discussion-between-davidhigh-and-blue-sky).